# ANTLR Removing nodes on tree walk

Tags: c#, parsing, tree, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I asked this on the ANTLR mailing list archives, but I didn't get a reply, so I'll try here.

Is there a problem with deleting a node/tree during a tree walk? I want to find any specific subtrees and get rid of them. I thought this rule would work...

```
attribute  : ^(ATTRIBUTE ID ATTR_VALUE) -> ;
```

But I get a NullPointerException.

Also, Can you write general rules to match trees with a range of root tokens?

```
tree : : ^(root attribute+ children+=.*) -> ^(root $children*);

fragment root : A | B;
```

I seem to be getting EmptyRewriteExceptions all the time :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a problem with deleting a node/tree during a tree walk?

That *can* go wrong in some cases. For example, whenever `attribute` (you've just rewritten to be removed) becomes the root of some other tree. There might be other causes, but that is one of them. When `attribute` will always be a lead in the tree, I don't think it can do any harm. Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) if this doesn't answer your question (be sure to post an actual SSCCE!).

> Also, Can you write general rules to match trees with a range of root tokens?

No, the operator `+=` creates a `List` of `Common[Token/Tree]`s. You'll need to move the `.*` to another rule, something like this (untested!):

```
tree : ^(root attribute+ children) -> ^(root children);

children : .* ;
```